# textfield value not retained after submit or refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to build a script that retains its value after a page refresh or submit, but I cannot get it to work. At the moment the page refreshes and the textfield resets instead of the value being retained. I hope someone can show me where I am going wrong, any help is greatly appreciated,

```js
document.getElementById("cmtx_comment").value = localStorage.getItem("comment");

function saveComment() {
    var comment = document.getElementById("cmtx_comment").value;
    if (comment == "") {
        alert("Please enter a comment in first!");
        return false;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("comment", comment);
    alert("Your comment has been saved!");
    
    location.reload();
    return false;
    //return true;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return saveComment();">
    <input type="text" name="cmtx_comment" id="cmtx_comment" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

many thanks in advance.

Comment: The code looks ok. It will not run here nor in JSFiddle because of sandbox, but should run on your own server. The assignment statement has to be after the field has rendered so perhaps you need to wrap in onload or place the code after the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code with my local pc. It does not work when I tried by putting the javascript code with `<script>` tags above the html content.

But when I moved the JS code along with the `<script>` tags just before the end of `</body>` tag. It worked.

Comment: Hey guys, it works now, thanks very much for your help:)